# Cookbook_file is not copying resource

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, cookbook

I'm trying to copy a file that's included with a cookbook.
This doesn't seem to be working:

```
cookbook_file node[:confluence][:mysql_jar] do
    path "#{node[:confluence][:install_path]}/confluence/WEB-INF/lib/"
    action :create_if_missing
end
```

I've checked the paths and they all have write permissions..
Also the included file has been placed under...

> Cookbook_name --> files --> default --> mysql.jar

Comment: What is the value of `node.confluence.mysql_jar`?

Comment: Is this snippet of code's recipe, and file you're referencing in the same cookbook. If not, how are you invoking Chef? Chef-solo? Vagrant? How did you include the cookbook? Using metadata, or "include_recipe"?